# La depuración de Visual Studio Community 2022 no funciona si pongo puntos de parada

Tags: blazor, visual-studio-2022

Estoy utilizando Visual Studio Community 2022 para un proyecto en Blazor Web Assembly. Resulta que de un momento a otro, si pongo algún punto de parada en el proyecto, la ventana del navegador se cierra nada más iniciar la depuración.

Esto no sucede también cuando pongo el punto de parada incluso en una función que no se ejecuta al iniciar. Es decir, que **solo por el simple hecho de haber un punto de parada en cualquier parte del código, la depuración ya no funciona**.

Estoy usando Google Chrome para depurar, pero cambiando a otros navegadores como Edge o Firefox sucede lo mismo. También he probado a reparar la instalación de Visual Studio, reiniciar el equipo, actualizar a la última versión y todo eso, pero no ha servido de nada tampoco.

EDIT: También he borrado la carpeta .vs del proyecto, pero no ha servido de nada, de hecho, ocurre en todos los proyectos.

Comment: Yo lo que hago en este tipo de situaciones es verificar si el problema es del proyecto o del VS. Para eso creo un nuevo proyecto y verifico si el problema se presenta también ahí. De no hacerlo, paso todo el proyecto viejo a un nuevo proyecto, creo que es más rápido que estar tratando de solucionar un problema irrepetible.

Comment: Lo de copiar el proyecto en otro proyecto nuevo no me ha funcionado. Por ahí he leido que  habilitando o deshabilitando la depuració RPC se puede arreglar, pero no se donde se hace eso en las opciones

Comment: Me contagiaste la maldicion, me pasa lo mismo. En mi caso en un proyecto nuevo no ocurre el problema. Creo que tiene que ver con el https, yo borré el certificado ssl y no solucionó nada